# Finding the R interpreter on MacOS

Tags: r, macos, intellij-idea, pycharm

I've been working with R quite a while and I'm trying to switch to PyCharm CE as an IDE (because at work R Studio is not allowed for some security reason). I was wondering if there is a way to display the path to the R interpreter in R, like there is a way to display the lib path by typing `.library`. The background of course is to set the correct interpreter in PyCharm but doing it in the R console would make this a programming question and therefore fit for StackOverflow.

I'm on MacOS

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the path to your R interpreter from the R console. (1) Is that correct? (2) If so, does `Sys.which("R")` give you the information you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly it. If you want to, you can make this an answer to gain some internet points by me accepting your answer :P 

For anyone interested: The interpreter is in "/usr/local/bin/R" which is a symbolic link to "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R", which is what I've been looking for. Thank you, @duckmayr

Comment: Answer added. Glad it helped, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the location of the interpreter using

```
Sys.which("R")
```

which on my machine, for example, returns

```
           R 
"/usr/bin/R"
```

From `help("Sys.which")`:

> [Return] Value:
>   A character vector of ... either the full path to the executable or some indication that no executable of that name was found.